# How to change the background color for google chart API, what am i doing wrong

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-api

here's is my code, what's wrong with it as far the chart background color goes ...

i know everything else works, but i cannot change the background color whatsoever.and i keep looking at the documentation and i keep coming to the same conclusion... Nothing.

the code itself retrieves all of the specified variables, builds the chart and changes the **HTML background, but fails to receive the chart background color change

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <?php echo "<style> body, div {background-color: #".$_GET['color']."} </style>"?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);


      var goal = <?php echo $_GET['goal']; ?>;
      var complete = <?php echo $_GET['complete']; ?>;
      var dmr = <?php echo $_GET['dmr']; ?>;
      var wysb = <?php echo $_GET['wysb']; ?>;
      function drawStuff() {

        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Type', 'Quantity:'],
          ["Goal", goal],
          ["Complete", complete],
          ["DMR", dmr],
          ["W.Y.S.B.", wysb],
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Productivity Monitor',
          width: 900,
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          chart: { title: 'Productivity Monitor',
                   subtitle: 'Comparative Chart with color indicator background' },
          bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
          backgroundColor :{fill : '<?php echo "#".$_GET["color"]; ?>' },
          axes: {
            x: {
              0: { side: 'top', label: 'Percentage'} // Top x-axis.
            }
          },
          bar: { groupWidth: "90%" }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top_x_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you change `fill : '<?php echo "#".$_GET["color"]; ?>' ` with hardcoded color, does it change?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

Instead of this:

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

From https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart:

> The Material Charts are in beta. The appearance and interactivity are
>   largely final, but many of the options available in Classic Charts are
>   not yet available in them. You can find a list of options that are not
>   yet supported in this issue.
>
> Also, the way options are declared is not finalized, so you must
>   convert your options by replacing this line:
>
> chart.draw(data, options);
>
> ...with this:
>
> chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));